# Show color permanently on v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the color of the text text filed to display its current state, but v-text-field shows the color only if it is focused on.
Is there a way to show it permanently?

thanks in Advance.

*I want it like this:*

[image: i want it like this:]

*but it's like this:*

[image]

I have tried using css, but it seems i can only change the label and input slot:

```
.edited >>> .v-text-field__slot input { 
   color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below is represented through a pseudo element on `v-input__slot`. You can target it with the `:before` selector.

```
.edited >>> .v-input__slot:before {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer. It only worked when I added .v-input__control as well: 
.edited >>> .v-input__control > .v-input__slot:before {}. And the color disappears when i hover over it